# Python Can the command-line arguments required set different depending on the condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use argparse for command-line arguments

But required arguments is differ by condition.

For example, first parameter is --o.

When --o is 1, required arguments is --from and --to, but if --o is 2, required arguments is --end and --path

parser.add_argument has required property, can I set differently depending on the condition?

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test')
parser.add_argument('--o', required=True, help='1 or 2')
parser.add_argument('--from', required=if(--o is 1))
parser.add_argument('--to', required=if(--o is 1))
parser.add_argument('--end', required=if (--o is 2))
parser.add_argument('--path', required=if (--o is 2))
```

Is this possible? Or is there another way?

I use python 3.6.

Comment: I think you should enforce this in your code. Using subparsers (https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers) forsuch trivial thing would be too much.